# Compose navigation: Go to top-level destination when clicking on navigation bar item

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, androidx, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using Jetpack Compose and androidx-navigation-compose.

Generally, I like the save/restore state mechanism when switching between bottom navigation tabs.

However, if I'm in a detail screen of a particular tab and I click on the tab again I wnat the app to navigate to the respective top level destination of that tab - opposed to doing nothing. How can I achieve this behavior?

The behavior I described is not implemented in Now-in-Android.
However, it used to be the default behavior when setting up a Bottom Bar with androidx navigation - before Compose.

I tried to built a minimal example, which can be found [here](https://github.com/p-fischer/compose-navigation-example).

Here is the most relevant part:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    bottomBar = {
        NavigationBar {
            bottomBarItems.forEach { item ->
                val screen = item.screen
                NavigationBarItem(
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                    label = { Text(item.title) },
                    selected = screen == currentTopLevelDestination.screen,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                            // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                            // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                            // on the back stack as users select items
                            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                            // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                            // reselecting the same item
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item

                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

    }
) { paddingValues ->
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = TopLevelDestination.HOME.route,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
    ) {
        navigation(
            route = TopLevelDestination.HOME.route,
            startDestination = Screen.Home.route,
        ) {
            composable(Screen.Home.route) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.HomeDetail.route) }) {
                        Text("Go to Home Detail")
                    }
                }
            }
            composable(Screen.HomeDetail.route) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    Text("Home Detail")
                }
            }
        }
        navigation(
            route = TopLevelDestination.MORE.route,
            startDestination = Screen.More.route,
        ) {
            composable(Screen.More.route) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.MoreDetail.route) }) {
                        Text("Go to More Detail")
                    }
                }
            }
            composable(Screen.MoreDetail.route) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    Text("More Detail")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is the following behavior:

1. App starts in Home screen
2. Navigate to Home Detail
3. Tap on Home bottom navigation item

-> I want to go back to Home

Comment: This is one of the reasons we should avoid showing navigation bars in detail screens. It may lead to various navigation issues and also be misleading to user. Use a back icon to allow returning to previous / dashboard screen. Play around with some popular apps - you will observe that the nav bar is almost never shown on detail screen.

Comment: @DerekK Gmail, Spotify, and Now in Android for example do use navigation bars on details screens. Conceptually, I don't see a problem with it. The behavior I'm describing used to be the default behavior before compose navigation.

Comment: Having a navigation bar on detail screens adds complexity, for sure, but it also brings the benefit of quicker navigation across the app.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this working in the [GitHub sample](https://github.com/p-fischer/compose-navigation-example)

The initial idea to keep track of the currently selected bottom navigation tab was correct.
It works if the navigation stack is not saved & restored if an already active tab is clicked.

Here is the most relevant code

```kotlin
@Composable
internal fun AppNavigationBar(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val currentTopLevelDestination by navController.currentTabItemAsState()

    NavigationBar {
        bottomBarItems.forEach { item ->
            val isTabAlreadySelected = item == currentTopLevelDestination
            NavigationBarItem(
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                label = { Text(item.title) },
                selected = isTabAlreadySelected,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigateToTabItem(
                        item = item,
                        restoreTabStack = !isTabAlreadySelected,
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Adds an [NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener] to this [NavController] and updates the
 * returned [State] which is updated as the destination changes.
 */
@Composable
private fun NavController.currentTabItemAsState(): State<TabItem> {
    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(TabItem.Home) }

    DisposableEffect(this) {
        val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when {
                destination.hierarchy.any { it.route == TabItem.More.navGraphRoute } -> {
                    selectedItem.value = TabItem.More
                }

                // TopLevelDestination.HOME is the start destination and, therefore, part of any stack
                else -> {
                    selectedItem.value = TabItem.Home
                }
            }
        }
        addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)

        onDispose {
            removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
        }
    }

    return selectedItem
}

private fun NavHostController.navigateToTabItem(
    item: TabItem,
    restoreTabStack: Boolean
) {
    navigate(item.navGraphRoute) {
        // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
        // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
        // on the back stack as users select items
        popUpTo(graph.findStartDestination().id) {
            saveState = restoreTabStack
        }
        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
        // reselecting the same item
        launchSingleTop = true
        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
        restoreState = restoreTabStack
    }
}
```